# Building a kernel module on RPI 4 sanitizer problem

Tags: kernel-module, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to build a kernel module on RPI4, I installed kernel headers with

```sh
sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

the *Makefile* is the following:

```make
obj-m += soft_uart.o
soft_uart-objs := module.o raspberry_soft_uart.o queue.o
RELEASE = $(shell uname -r)
LINUX = /home/m3s/linux-f2f7e4b23d8788e96f81a7522b2f703e51c53e70
all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(LINUX) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(LINUX) M=$(PWD) clean
install:
    sudo install -m 644 -c soft_uart.ko /lib/modules/$(RELEASE)
```

simply compiling with make in the directory this is the error:

```
make -C /home/m3s/linux-f2f7e4b23d8788e96f81a7522b2f703e51c53e70 M=/home/m3s/application/soft_uart modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/m3s/linux-f2f7e4b23d8788e96f81a7522b2f703e51c53e70'
  CC [M]  /home/m3s/application/soft_uart/module.o
  CC [M]  /home/m3s/application/soft_uart/raspberry_soft_uart.o
  CC [M]  /home/m3s/application/soft_uart/queue.o
  LD [M]  /home/m3s/application/soft_uart/soft_uart.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
ERROR: "__sanitizer_cov_trace_cmp4" [/home/m3s/application/soft_uart/soft_uart.ko] undefined!
ERROR: "__sanitizer_cov_trace_const_cmp1" [/home/m3s/application/soft_uart/soft_uart.ko] undefined!
ERROR: "__sanitizer_cov_trace_pc" [/home/m3s/application/soft_uart/soft_uart.ko] undefined!
ERROR: "__sanitizer_cov_trace_const_cmp4" [/home/m3s/application/soft_uart/soft_uart.ko] undefined!
ERROR: "__sanitizer_cov_trace_switch" [/home/m3s/application/soft_uart/soft_uart.ko] undefined!
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:94: __modpost] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1622: modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/m3s/linux-f2f7e4b23d8788e96f81a7522b2f703e51c53e70'
make: *** [Makefile:10: all] Error 2
```

the module *soft_uart.ko* is not created but there aren't other errors.
Any idea where's the problem with module creation?

Comment: Looks like your module is built with sanitizing option. Have you tried to build "hello world" type of module for your kernel? Also you could run `make VERBOSE=1` (which would show the full compilation line instead of just `CC [M]  /home/m3s/application/soft_uart/module.o`) and check that line for presence of `-fsanitize` option.

Comment: building an HelloWorld module seems to be ok, so the problem seems to be in the module soft_uart but I can't understand why, the module is the same that is builded without problem on raspberry 3. The make verbose=1 do not produce addictional info. I can't understand where is the "sanitize" option.

Comment: Sorry, it is `make V=1` which causes verbose build of the Linux kernel. As simple module builds without errors, the root of the problem seems to be in the sources of `soft_uart` module. That means we need that sources (and better in the form of [mcve]).

Comment: Thanks, the problem is now to solved using a makefile that doesn't specify the kernel, in fact the problem was that the kernel suggested seems to be invalid /home/m3s/linux-f2f7e4b23d8788e96f81a7522b2f703e51c53e70  thanks